# Why is the bundle not saved when I create a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to pass a some data in a bundle when I create a fragment and for some reason the bundle is null when I read it in `onCreate` method.

Country Fragment class

```
public class CountryFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String EXTRA_COUNTRY_ID = "com.sitram.country_id";

    private Country mCountry;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        UUID countryID = (UUID)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_COUNTRY_ID);
        mCountry = CountryBank.get(getActivity()).getCountry(countryID);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_fragment, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    public static CountryFragment newInstance(UUID crimeID){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_COUNTRY_ID, crimeID);

        CountryFragment fragment = new CountryFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

}
```

CountryPagerActivity which creates the fragment:

```
public class CountryPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ArrayList<Country> mCountryList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstances) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstances);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);

        mCountryList = CountryBank.get(this).getCountryList();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mCountryList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
                Country mCountry = mCountryList.get(arg0);
                return CountryFragment.newInstance(mCountry.getCountryId());
            }
        });

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                Country mCountry = mCountryList.get(arg0);
                if (mCountry.getContinentName() != null){
                    setTitle(mCountry.getCountryName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
        });

        UUID countryID = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(CountryFragment.EXTRA_COUNTRY_ID);
        for (int i=0; i<mCountryList.size(); i++) {
            if (mCountryList.get(i).getCountryId().equals(countryID)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting it from the `savedInstanceState` which is only used for fragment that is created again due to orientation change, home buttons is pressed, etc.

it supposed to be from the fragment's bundle

**sample:**

***change this:***

```
UUID countryID = (UUID)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_COUNTRY_ID);
```

***to:***

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
UUID countryID  = (UUID)bundle.getSerializable(EXTRA_COUNTRY_ID);
```

Comment: Yeah, that has always been confusing on my end as well whenever I need it.  Logically to me gaining access from the bundle directly is the logical course of action.

Answer (score 0):

The Bundle you are trying to access (`onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, `onActivityCreated()`) is the one filled when onSaveInstanceState() is called when a configuration change happens.

you need to use `getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_COUNTRY_ID)` instead.